# What does "comment everywhere" mean?

Tags: support, comments

It must mean something different from what I'd thought: [this user](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/13546/tina-aspiala) joined today and has never asked or answered anything, and has 1 reputation.  However, [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/43963/10041) has a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/13546/tina-aspiala?tab=activity) by the same user.  But the [privileges page](https://english.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) says the "comment everywhere" privilege is only available to users who have 50 rep or more.  Am I misunderstanding the meaning of "comment everywhere"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your understanding is correct. The comment was originally posted as an answer and was converted to a comment by me (something that can be done by any mod).

Answer (score 1):

The comment is an answer transformed in a comment; this is also reported from the comment left from who did it (waiwai933).

[image: screenshot]